# How to make metisMenu auto expand on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [metisMenu](https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu) for administrator panel. I want to make my sidebar menu auto expanded on mouse hover with smooth speed. I'm using freeware [advance admin template](http://binarytheme.com/btlivedemos/2014/09/16/advance-admin/index.html) by binarytheme. I have done auto expand on mouse by using following CSS code but the speed expand is very high and not under my control.

CSS Code for auto expand

```
.nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The above code works but to add delay to expand I use jQuery but this does not work.

My jQuery code:

```
$('.nav li').hover(function(){
    $('li').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I also use transitional effect `transition:all 200ms ease-in-out 0s !important;` to make smooth auto expand but this does not work.

Comment: Look at http://mm.onokumus.com/mm-vertical-hover.html – try .sidebar-nav .metismenu > li {flex: 1 1 auto;} if it does not look OK in Safari. Also 200ms is 1/5 of a second. Pretty fast ;-)

Answer (score 1):

MetisMenu support animate with [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) like this:

```
<ul class="animated bounce"> ... </ul>
```

You also need to include animate.min.css in the document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
```

If it does not work try eliminating any conflicts by temporarily disabling other CSS files in your template to narrow down the problem.

[Examples](http://mm.onokumus.com/mm-animate.html) / [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fn8ftqna/2/)

[Hover example.](http://mm.onokumus.com/mm-vertical-hover.html)